# Bash script pre close command

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04

I have a script which manages some settings on a remote PC via ssh such that this server forwards ip traffic. At the moment I have a connect and disconnect script and I would like to bundle them into one easy to handle script. Now this bundle starts the connection and waits for a user input to start the disconnect script.

The problem with that, I often forget to close the script, have a PC restart or other, hence the remote PC ip forwarding is not reset. So my question is, is there any way to implement the invocation of the disconnection script such that it is always automatically called if the script finishes or crashes (process killed, bash console forced to close, ...)?

Thank you very much, Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trap` (see `man bash` for details) should be what you are looking for. A small example:

```
#!/bin/bash 
function cleanup() {
    echo "We're done."
    exit 0
}
trap cleanup SIGHUP SIGTERM

while true; do
    sleep 1
done
```

Not an ubuntu (systemd) expert myself but I presume any init would first try to kill remaining processes (my rc.K would go with `SIGHUP` and then `SIGTERM` before resorting to `SIGKILL` (the latter we cannot intercept)). You may need to experiment a bit (for a bit more on signals have a look at `man -s7 signal`)

You can also handle `0` for regular exists or for instance `SIGINT` (aka `[Ctrl+c]`).

---

EDIT: To elaborate a bit more on a follow-up question in a comment.

Since in the above example I would return from the trap handler back into the infinite loop, I had to include an explicit `exit` call. However if you also caught and handled `EXIT` (or `0`, same meaning) with it, you would see the trap handler entered twice when catching any (not just plain `exit`) signal (e.g. `SIGHUP`). Once for the signal, and second time for the `EXIT`.

If you want want to make sure your script ends after the handler is done, you can still call `exit 0`, but after you have reset the trap associated with it:

```
#!/bin/bash
function cleanup() {
    echo "We're done."
    trap - EXIT
    exit 0
}
trap cleanup EXIT SIGHUP SIGTERM SIGINT

while true; do
    sleep 1
done
```

That is probably want your use case calls for. The other option would be, if you did not necessarily need the script to end and you could have it just continue its way towards its "natural end", you could also just skip the `exit` in the handler.

Comment: Hi Ondrej, thank you very much for your comment, this is what I wanted. However I tried to capture the terminal window being closed, which leads to a double execution of cleanup, do you have another idea why?

Comment: @MartinHerrmann Please, post your code (or relevant snippet). Off the bet I would guess that you registered your "cleanup" function with a signal being caught (`SIGHUP` likely for terminal being closed) and as well "normal" `exit`. Which can happen within the handler and would cause it to re-enter. In my case I had to exit ('cuz the loop would just keep running (and I would probably reset the trap of `EXIT` in that case). But if you're script would just end anyways, you can skip that exit and you should not see the `trap` handler run twice. I could try to go into more detail later, if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed edit, it works now as intended, thank you very much!